# scaled $p$-norm, $p$-average, limit $p\to 0+$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Given a vector $v\in\mathbb{R^n}$, the $p$-average be given by
$$
\text{avg}_p := \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum |v_i|^p \right)^{1/p}.
$$
For $p=1$ this is the average of the $|v_i|$, for $p=2$ it's the [root mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square).
Does this thing have an actual name? (Except scaled $p$-norm of course.)

Its limit $p\to\infty$ is $\max(|v|)$. What's the limit for $p\to 0+$? I played with uniformly randomly distributed entries and it seems the limit exists (as opposed to the $p$-norm):

[image]

Comment: The limit as $p \to 0+$ is $e^{\frac  1n \sum \ln |v_i|}$

Comment: Wow, cool. Where does this come from?

Comment: This is a well known result from measure theory. It is available in Rudin's RCA and it has also appeared earlier on MSE.

Comment: If you promote your reply to an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Perhaps $\left(\prod |v_i|\right)^{1/n}$ is the better representation as avoids difficulties if one entry is exactly 0.

Comment: I have used the convention $e^{ \ln 0}=0$ in my comment. This is what Rudin does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Kavi Rama Murthy:
$$
\lim_{p\to 0+}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum |v_i|^p \right)^{1/p}
=
\left(\prod|v_i|\right)^{1/n}
$$
(The geometric mean.) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean.